# Installing Eagle Cad on Fedora 20 (FEL Spin, 64-Bit)

Tags: fedora, cad

I have been using Debian based distributions of Linux for about a year now and I want to try out Fedora. I downloaded the Electronic Lab spin but I want to install Eagle CAD, which I understand uses 32-bit libraries.

I have found some information on some other sites that all recommend using yum to install these libraries:

```
sudo yum install libstdc++.i686 libXrender.i686 libXrandr.i686 libXcursor.i686 freetype.i686 fontconfig.i686 libXi.i686
```

I tried to just install the first two listed there but I got this on the output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: mirror.steadfast.net
 * rpmfusion-free: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.steadfast.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libXrender.i686 0:0.9.8-2.fc20 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) for package: libXrender-0.9.8-2.fc20.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libX11.so.6 for package: libXrender-0.9.8-2.fc20.i686
---> Package libstdc++.i686 0:4.8.2-7.fc20 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc_s.so.1(GLIBC_2.0) for package: libstdc++-4.8.2-7.fc20.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_4.2.0) for package: libstdc++-4.8.2-7.fc20.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.3) for package: libstdc++-4.8.2-7.fc20.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0) for package: libstdc++-4.8.2-7.fc20.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc_s.so.1 for package: libstdc++-4.8.2-7.fc20.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.18-11.fc20 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) for package: glibc-2.18-11.fc20.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so for package: glibc-2.18-11.fc20.i686
---> Package libX11.i686 0:1.6.1-1.fc20 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libxcb.so.1 for package: libX11-1.6.1-1.fc20.i686
---> Package libgcc.i686 0:4.8.2-7.fc20 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libxcb.i686 0:1.9.1-3.fc20 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libXau.so.6 for package: libxcb-1.9.1-3.fc20.i686
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.15.3-1.fc20 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libXau.i686 0:1.0.8-2.fc20 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:
       
         1. You have an upgrade for libstdc++ which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of libstdc++ of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude libstdc++.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.
       
         2. You have multiple architectures of libstdc++ installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.
       
         3. You have duplicate versions of libstdc++ installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.
       
       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).
       
       Protected multilib versions: libstdc++-4.8.2-7.fc20.i686 != libstdc++-4.8.2-1.fc20.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: libgcc-4.8.2-7.fc20.i686 != libgcc-4.8.2-1.fc20.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: nss-softokn-freebl-3.15.3-1.fc20.i686 != nss-softokn-freebl-3.15.2-2.fc20.x86_64
```

When I try to run the installer script provided by Cad Soft I get the following:

```
./eagle-lin-6.5.0.run: /tmp/eagle-setup.3796/eagle-6.5.0/bin/eagle: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

From others I am guessing this is showing up because there is something wrong with my 32-Bit libraries?

Since I am new to Fedora I am also new to the YUM package manager. I also realize that I could use KiCAD but I need Eagle for work and I would like to see if I can get this system up to speed with what I need at work.

Comment: Try running 'yum update' and then follow the directions given for [Eagle CAD install on Fedora 19 x86_64](http://www.jann.cc/2013/11/28/installing_cadsoft_eagle_6_5_in_fedora_19_x86_64.html).  Disclaimer:  ***YMMV!***

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did do the `yum update` and tried to install those libraries from that link you posted. I got the same output from YUM. Where it says that there is a protected multilib version, does that mean that it won't let it update the x86_64 version? Is it possible that the FEL spin developers prevented it from updating because of some dependency issues or otherwise? Thank you

Comment: Not sure if that spin has 'yum-utils' installed, but does 'package-cleanup --cleandupes' fix the multilib problems?  If not, does 'yum check' report problems?

Comment: I tried `yum-utils` and it was not installed. I did run `package-cleanup --cleandupes`and it displayed a lot. First it displayed 160 packages that will be erased. Then it displayed `Removing PackageKit-device-rebind.x86_64 0:0.8.13-1.fc20 - e due to obsoletes from installed PackageKit-0.8.15-1.fc20.x86_64` 600 times and then stated that `Depsolving loop limit reached`. It says that I can try using `--skip broken to work around the problem`. It then shows the output from `yum check`, whish is 160 pre-existing rpmdb problems. Is this all from this particular spin? Thanks for any other help

Comment: Seems like an update was interupted some time in the past which left you with a mess in your yum and rpm db.  First I would try the suggested '--skip-broken' option to see if some problems can be fixed and then with some things fixed, try it without the '--skip-broken'.  Before proceeding with Eagle CAD install, your F20 needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that it was the fix that I was looking for, but I did get Eagle Cad installed on a fresh install of the regular Fedora 20 (64-bit) by following the link provided by rickhg12hs in the comments of the original post. I am not sure what caused all of the problems with yum and rpm db. Thank you to rickhg12hs for the help though!